# VC++ : How to prevent esc from closing a dialog box (not mfc)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dialog

How could I prevent esc from closing a dialog box?

I searched for this topic, but all I found was for MFC (You can overwrite PreTranslateMessage function in MFC). but my program is written in Windows API, **not MFC**.

I tried to catch all Keyboard messages in Dialog procedure, but none of them works. I also tried using subclassing in dialog box, but it didn't work too.

How could I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine whether it's from the system menu easily enough -- check out the "return value" section of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647591(VS.85).aspx) to see how.

If you can't determine whether it's from the ESCAPE key or a button, you could always get around that by using a different identifier for your Cancel button.

Answer (score 9):

Handle WM_COMMAND and check for IDCANCEL. Then do not pass the control to the default window procedure.

Comment: With this approach you will also disable closing of the dialog with the `X` button on its title bar, or from its system menu.

Comment: @Ivan We can just ignore `IDCANCEL` case in our dialog-box procedure, in order to prevent dialog-box being closed by ESC key.  There is nothing to do with "default window procedure", because in user dialog-box procedure (the function we pass to `DialogBoxParam`), we never call `DefWindowProc`.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Windows API, if you don't want the ESC key to close dialog-box, but want the window-title Close button(or Alt+F4) to close it, you can tune you code as follows:

Step 1/2: In WM_COMMAND processing, Do NOT respond to `id==IDCANCEL` case.

In classic code from Charles Petzold *Programming Windows 5th-ed*, he calls `EndDialog()` beneath `id==IDCANCEL`, so the dialog-box gets finally closed. You must NOT call `EndDialog()` here.

Step 2/2: Process `WM_SYSCOMMAND` in your dialog-box procedure, like this:

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
{
    if(wParam==SC_CLOSE)
    {
        // Use any value you want to return to DialogBox() caller instead of 4.
        EndDialog(hdlg, 4); 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`WM_SYSCOMMAND` message is triggered by window-title Close button and Alt+F4, but not by ESC key, so it works.